# Lattice modifier deforms or stretches my geometry

Tags: lattice

I'm modeling a car and I made this scene to illustrate the problem i'm having.

I have the geometry of my car and would like to use a lattice so i can shape the car correctly. When applying it however, it stretches my geometry as seen in the pictures.

The object (or car geometry) has its scale and position (+rotation) applied.
The lattice object never moved position, I used edit mode to change the overall shape and position of the lattice. And added the subdivisions in the lattice tab.

Can someone tell me why this is happening? Or are there other ways i could do this? Thank you!

Here is the link to the file if you'd like to check it out yourself;
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b66Rq3uprQROoIRWfVWOMMlZCrmh91TP/view?usp=sharing
[image: the geometry i want to change the shape of using a lattice modifier. Scale and location is applied.]

[image: The lattice object. Scale is also applied. I used edit mode to change the position of the lattice to the right spot.]

[image: When applying the lattice, my object stretches.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lattice object scale in object mode.

your lattice  scale is not correct

blender file --->
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/e6ir168d406rk5sw6w5g1/lattice-problem.blend?rlkey=e3wdiz35jbx7fwn4wdbcqhuun&dl=0

Comment: I should not apply the scale of my lattice it seems like. thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thanks for the posts. This is not a regular forum, according to site rules [links to answers are not answers](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2382) if the link goes missing your answer becomes an empty shell without content. Answers should be substantial and stand on their own without relying on external data like links, videos or images. Instead of having users go through external links, either describe essential parts of the process here, linking the source, or posts these in the comments section instead.

Comment: yes you are right. but this is not a zip file it blender file. artists believe this file. this question answer is short one liner. this is only lattice object  scaling problem.